# Arduino Yun - how it's detected over the wifi

Tags: arduino, embedded-linux, arduino-ide, arduino-yun

I wonder how the arduino IDE recognizes the ip address of the arduinoYun board over wifi/ethernet. So that I can implement it myself over mobile application.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried sniffing the network to see exchanged packets ? It can help you detecting the protocol used

Comment: Thanks, I'll try, but i think it will be hard to do that. I think there's some sort of protocol for recognizing that !!!

Comment: Yes it will be hard but I don't have any other lead in mind, sorry

Comment: You can certainly find more info here: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Yun uses Bonjour services (port 5353) for auto-discovery on a wireless network. For more information, [look here](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoYun#toc13).